# In ionic Cordova android platform, aar file contents are not merging in ionic after generating apk

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I am trying to use .aar file in ionic project. 
after running the app, its not containing or I am unable to access the classes from .aar file. checked with aapt command also, nothing has merged.
Has anyone come across the some same behaviour in ionic/cordova android platform.